# Filtering data row value in column DataGridView with value inside two textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

thank you for your time.

I'm trying to write the program to filter the value from CSV file.  I have three textbox and one datagridview in my form.

So far i managed to parse the CSV into the DataGridView. The problem occur when i trying to filter the value inside the first column by using two value in textbox.

So far, i just managed to selected the row with value given in the Textbox. How can i possibly to filter the datagridview like below:-

```
 Textbox1 value < value in column > Textbox2 value
```

This is example of my csv files:-

```
 Northing,Easting,Result 
 645789.900,578778.982,6.78 
 645782.892,578767.289,5.54 
 645801.435,579213.430,6.78 
 645804.156,579445.670,5.79 
 645980.188,582544.389,8.90 
 645983.456,582667.344,8.79 
 646590.253,584788.212,7.60 
 646800.789,585690.312,2.50 
 646909.452,585780.212,4.30 
 647900.323,585890.345,6.89
```

This is code i using so far:-

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.Data;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using DgvFilterPopup;

      namespace ZoningParameter
 {
  /// <summary>
  /// Description of MainForm.
  /// </summary>
  public partial class MainForm : Form
  {
    public MainForm()
    {
        //
        // The InitializeComponent() call is required for Windows Forms designer 
        //
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor code after the InitializeComponent() call.
        //
    }






    void BtnSelectClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
            {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
                tbxSelectFile.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                myStream.Close();

            }

        } 
    }

    void BtnCancelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tbxSelectFile.Text = null;
    }

    void BtnGenerateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          //  get all lines of csv file
        string[] str = File.ReadAllLines(tbxSelectFile.Text);

        // create new datatable
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();


        // get the column header means first line
        string[] temp = str[0].Split(',');

        // creates columns of gridview as per the header name
        foreach (string t in temp)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(t, typeof(string));
        }

        // now retrive the record from second line and add it to datatable
        for (int i = 1; i < str.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] t = str[i].Split(',');

            dt.Rows.Add(t);
        }

        DataGridValue.DataSource = dt;


        }



    void BtnFilterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        // create new DataTable

        DataTable dt = ((DataTable)DataGridValue.DataSource);

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridValue.Rows)
        {
            // Test if the first column of the current row equals
            // the value in the text box
            if ((String)row.Cells["Northing"].Value == tbxX1.Text)
            {
                // we have a match
                row.Selected = true;
            }
            else
            {
                row.Selected = false;

            }


        }
```

Can someone show me the right way how to do this? Thank you very much.

EDITED!!!

Thank you therak for your help. This is working code

```
 dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Northing < '{0}' AND Northing > '{1}'",tbxX2.Text,  tbxX1.Text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is a [DataView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hy5b8exc(v=vs.110).aspx) which you can bind to a DataGridView.DataSource.
DataViews can be filtered/sorted etc. For more info about DataView have a loot at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx)

In your case it will be something like this:

```
DataView dv = ((DataTable)DataGridValue.DataSource).DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "ColumnName < TB1 AND ColumName > TB2"
Afterwards bind the DataView to your gridView
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I try your code but unfortunately it didnt work. `code` DataView dv = ((DataTable)DataGridValue.DataSource).DefaultView;
                dv.RowFilter = "Northing  < tbxX2.Text AND Northing  > tbxX1.Text"; `code` but the error come out the it cant find the column name of my textbox. Any suggestion?

Comment: try **`dv.RowFilter = String.Format("Nothing < '{0}' AND Nothing > '{1}'",tbxX2.Text, tbxX1.Text)"`** - if you tried it like you wrote in your comment then it didn'T compare with the actual text but was trying to compare a column named "tbxX2.Text" which it didn't find.

Comment: it's worked!!! Thank you very much therak. Your help is very much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter =
     string.Format("Northing = '{0}'", textBox2.Text);

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I try your statement and it only produce the value same as the textbox. Any ideas how to retrieve the range of value between two value in the two textbox? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this haven't tested it but might work for your situation:

```
void BtnFilterClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    // create new DataTable

    DataTable filteredDataTable = new DataTable();

    filteredDataTable.Columns.Add("csv column");

    DataTable dt = ((DataTable)DataGridValue.DataSource);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridValue.Rows)
    {
        // Test if the first column of the current row equals
        // the value in the text box
        if ((String)row.Cells["Northing"].Value == tbxX1.Text)
        {
            // we have a match
            filteredDataTable.Add(row)
        }

    }

    DataGridValue.DataSource = null;
    DataGridValue.DataSource = filteredDataTable;

}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. In result, the output produce single value only same as value i put in tbxX1.Text. However i would like to produce something in between two values from two textbox. Any ideas?