# How to filter datagridview with textbox and button click in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, textbox

I would like to filter my dataGridView (birthDay colum by month) for button click with a textbox.

If I type number 5 for the textbox, then I would display the rows which are containing number 5 as from month row.

```
var dataTable = (DataTable)DataGridView2.DataSource;
var dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;
dataView.RowFilter = string.Format("Month", birthdayMonth.Text);
DataGridView2.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;   
DataGridView2.Rows[0].Selected = true;
```

Comment: This works https://stackoverflow.com/a/34221819/2946329 compare it with yours.

Comment: It is not working for me :(

Comment: You're not looking close enough at the format of the RowFilter in S.Akbari's link. If you want only those rows where Month = 5 then you need to set the RowFilter to something like `string.Format("Month = {0}", birthdayMonth.Text` or at the very least just `Month = " + birthdayMonth.Text`

Comment: I am getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." For var dataView = dataTable.DefaultView;

Comment: No luck.
I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24864710/filtering-data-row-value-in-column-datagridview-with-value-inside-two-textbox) but I am very confused, so I don't know the final working code :( Anybody can help me out? Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Filtering DataGridView by a using textbox & two DataGridView without database

1. Make sure to add 2 DataGridViews
2. implement a .csv reader
3. Put a TextBox
4. Name them properly (textbox, 2 dgv)

In the first DataGridview create a Selection Changed 
event for the first DataGridView.

I used [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f878a041-1eb7-4978-bc4d-e50578fe6d7c/c-how-to-copy-a-selected-row-from-one-datagridview-to-another-datagridview-?forum=winforms) 
method:

`if (this.dgv2.DataSource != null)`

- > this.dgv2.DataSource = null;

`else`

- > this.dgv2.Rows.Clear();

`for (int i = 0; i < dgv1.SelectedRows.Count; i++)`

- > int index = dgv2.Rows.Add();

Then you can inser the wanted rows like:

- > dgv2.Rows[index].Cells["to"].Value = dgv1.SelectedRows[i].Cells["from"].Value.ToString();

After creating the Selection Changed event for the first DataGridView we have create a text based search, it can be with foreach loop.

Example: 
`foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)`

Then `if` and `else` methods

Like:

`if ((string)row.Cells["from"].Value == textbox.Text)`

Making statements:

- > row.Selected = false;
- > row.Visible = true;

`else`

- > row.Selected = false;
- > row.Visible = false;

Enjoy! :)